# Access request parameters from flask application deployed in openshift

Tags: python, http, flask, openshift

I have a python web app that carry's out calculations on data you send to it via  POST / GET parameters.
The app works perfectly on my machine, but when deployed to openshift, it fails to access the parameters with an error no 32 : Broken pipe

I then used this [quickstart](https://github.com/openshift-quickstart/flask-base) repo to just focus on server code and not app code.

Got to differentiate between a POST and GET request and ended there

here's the relevant python code :

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
    result = ""

    if request.method == "GET":
        name = request.form['name'] if "name" in request.form else ""
        result = "We received a GET request and the value for <name> is :%s" % name
    elif request.method == "POST":
        result = "We received a POST request"
    else :
        result = "We don't know what type of request we have received"

return result
```

So i just wanna know how i can access the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use Flask's development server in production. Use a proper WSGI server that can handle concurrent requests, like [Gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/). For now try turning on the server's threaded mode and see if it works.

```
app.run(host="x.x.x.x", port=1234, threaded=True)
```

Comment: Also, OpenShift may be throttling your requests. Try checking if upgrading your plan works.

Answer (score 0):

You can get form data from the POST request via:

```
name = request.form.get("name")
```

Refactor:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def index():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            name = request.form.get("name")
            result = "We received a POST request and the value for <name> is - {0}".format(name)
        else:
            result = "This is a GET request"
        return result
```

---

Refer to the [official Flask documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#incoming-request-data) to learn more about the Request object.